# Как правильно писать: мета-игра, метаигра или мета игра

Tags: орфография

Как правильно писать: мета-игра, метаигра или мета игра

Answer (score 2):

**МЕТА**... [от греч. metá - вслед, за, после, через] Первая часть сложных слов.

1. Обозначает уровень описания какого-нибудь объекта или системы (как правило, также описания), высшего по отношению к предыдущему описанию; "описание описания". Металингвистика, металогика, метатекст,  метаязык.
2. Обозначает выход за пределы чего-либо. Метагалактика, метагалактический, метафизика (2 зн.).

Но тренажер **Мета-Игра** - имя собственное, выбрано дефисное написание. В одной и той же статье встречаются обе формы: метаигра (нариц.) и Мета-игра (собств.)

[http://www.soling.su/2011/03/09/метаигра-](http://www.soling.su/2011/03/09/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0-)–-это-универсальная-образов/

Answer (score 1):

Мета... - приставка, пишется слитно.

Русский орфографический словарь Российской академии наук.
Отв. ред. В. В. Лопатин.

Answer (score 0):

[В орфографическом словаре слитно](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/rus_orthography/42397/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0)